# Can't connect GitHub Actions to AWS for Terraform deployment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions, amazon-iam

I've been trying to build a Node.js application and deploy the build artifact to AWS with Terraform, all inside of GitHub Actions and I'm having a headache connecting GitHub Actions to my AWS account/user.

I tried storing the secret access and access keys in the repository secrets and declaring that in my yaml file like this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_ARN }}
          aws-region: us-east-1

      - name: Install Node.js
        run: sudo apt-get install node

      - name: Install NPM
        run: sudo apt-get install npm

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Linter (ESLint)
        run: npm run lint

      - name: Install Prettier
        run: npm install --save-dev prettier

      - name: Formatter (Prettier)
        run: npm run prettier

      - name: Build application
        run: npm run build

      # This step outputs the URL of the built application
      - name: Output application URL
        run: echo "::set-output name=application_url::$(npm run build | grep 'Your application is running at' | awk '{print $NF}')"

      - name: Install Terraform
        run: sudo apt-get install terraform

      - name: Configure Terraform
        run: terraform init

      - name: Deploy Infrastructure
        run: terraform apply -var "application_url=${{ steps.deploy.outputs.application_url }}" --auto-approve
```

Once it gets to the 'Configure AWS Credentials' part, I get this error:

```
Run aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
    role-to-assume: ***
    aws-region: us-east-1
    audience: sts.amazonaws.com
Error: Credentials could not be loaded, please check your action inputs: Could not load credentials from any providers
```

I've also tried using the IAM role method and stored a trust policy (and eventually a role arn) in secrets on GHA but that gives the same error.

I have no problem just running the build by itself. The job is successful with in a little over a minute when I do that. It's the adding AWS deployment part that seems to be giving me a headache. I'm new to GitHub Actions so any help would be appreciated. Even ChatGPT and Bard can't seem to help me out with this one.

Comment: Please see [Updating your GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services#updating-your-github-actions-workflow) ([via](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/issues/271))

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials#assumerole-with-static-iam-credentials-in-repository-secrets) you can see the example

```
- name: Configure AWS Credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    aws-region: us-east-2
    role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
    role-external-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_EXTERNAL_ID }}
    role-duration-seconds: 1200
    role-session-name: MySessionName
```

I think you are missing the `access-key-id` and `secret-access-id`.

Note that this is not the best practice to do that, the best practice is to Assume Role directly using GitHub OIDC provider.